# Can I define a CodePipeline with Terraform that deploys my Terraform resources?

Tags: terraform, github, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to figure out the best way to automate the deployment of infrastructure resources defined in Terraform. Ideally, I'd like to deploy all my code — including resource definitions — in a CI/CD manner.

So, if I define an AWS CodePipeline that reads my Terraform code from GitHub, can I have that CodePipeline...deploy itself (+ any other AWS resources defined in the repo)?

**Update:**

I built this and tried to push a change through the pipeline that updated the CodeBuild image. It seems like the CodeBuild step to run Terraform succeeded in updating the pipeline, but then the "Build" stage that did this ended up in a "Cancelled" state with the message: `Pipeline definition was updated`.

So it seems like it sort of worked, but I may have to kick off a manual release of the most recent change after that. Any downsides/risks?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Sign into AWS Console

Step 2: Navigate to CodePipeline service

Step 3: Click on the “Create Pipeline” button

Step 4: Enter the Pipeline name and click on the “Next” button

Step 5: Select “GitHub” as Source provider and enter the following values

Repository: https://github.com/cloudacademy/cloud-academy-terraform-pipeline.git

Branch: master

Click on the “Next” button

Step 6: Select the following Build provider

AWS CodeBuild

Project name:

Click on the “Next” button

Step 7: Select the following Deploy provider

AWS CodeDeploy

Deployment provider: S3

Click on the “Next” button

Step 8: Review the values and click on the “Create Pipeline” button

Step 9: Select the following Build provider

AWS CodeBuild

Project name:

Click on the “Next” button

Step 10: Select the following Deploy provider

AWS CodeDeploy

Deployment provider: S3

Click on the “Next” button

Step 11: Review the values and click on the “Create Pipeline” button

Step 12: Select the following Build provider

AWS CodeBuild

Project name:

Click on the “Next” button

Step 13: Select the following Deploy provider

AWS CodeDeploy

Deployment provider: S3

Click on the “Next” button

Step 14: Review the values and click on the “Create Pipeline” button

Step 15: Select the following Build provider

AWS CodeBuild

Project name:

Click on the “Next” button

Step 16: Select the following Deploy provider

AWS CodeDeploy

Deployment provider: S3

Click on the “Next” button

Step 17: Review the values and click on the “Create Pipeline” button

Step 18: Review

Comment: I appreciate the thorough answer, but this seems to me like a step-by-step guide on how to create a Terraform pipeline. It looks like it is defined in the console at that (I'm not sure what the GitHub repo you meant to link does — I'm getting a 404). 

I'm more looking for the answer as to whether I can define a pipeline in Terraform and have it deploy itself and other AWS resources.